# Apache mod_rewrite to NginX rewrite help please

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have used an online converter to convert the following Apache mod_rewrite to NginX rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1 [R=301,L]
```

The output looked like this:

```
  if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
        rewrite /. /index.php last;
}
if ($http_host ~* "^www.(.*)$"){
        set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
        set $bref_1 $1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "1"){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$bref_1 permanent;
}
```

and although the conversion worked when added to a vhosts file, it has been pointed out to me that the conversion is poor and also http://docs.ngx.cc/en/latest/topics/depth/ifisevil.html

Can anybody help me with a 'proper' conversion please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This mostly should do the trick, the problem would be on what exactly u want to be passed to `index.php`

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /path/to/www;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri
    }
}
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 example.com;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried the rewrite but it didn't work for me I'm afraid.  Also I'm looking for a rewrite that will work with any domains rather than having to specify one..